# I have an issue updating my kali linux system and below is the output

Tags: kali-linux

```
─# apt-get update                                                      100 ⨯
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu impish InRelease
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:3 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                    
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: What is `http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu impish Release`? Can you remove it from sources.list?

Comment: why would you install an Ubuntu repository with backports of SDL2, a multimedia library, on Kali, which is neither a Ubuntu derivate, *nor* a general purpose Linux distro?

Comment: @maxwell what is your reason for using kali linux?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a non-Kali repository, which may have broken your Kali system irretrievably. Please read

- [Kali Network Repositories (/etc/apt/sources.list)](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/)
- [Should I Use Kali Linux?](https://www.kali.org/docs//introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/)

You can attempt to fix this situation with the following commands, which will reset your repository collection back to the standard set. However, depending on what you installed from a non-Kali repository you may still have package conflicts that cannot be resolved

```
find /etc/apt/sources.list* -type f -name '*.list' -exec mv -f {} {}.old \;
echo 'deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib' >/etc/apt/sources.list

apt-get update
```

Comment: I'd like to especially stress the "Should I Use Kali Linux?" post by the Kali maintainers. A lot of the Kali questions here are sadly frustrated Linux beginners that for some reason ended up using Kali, which *specifically* does not try to be useful for them.